# fMRI: Is there a minimum sample size for performing Principal Component Analysis for dimension reduction?

Tags: pca, sample-size, small-sample

I'm performing a functional MRI study and I need to analyze the relationship between 198.350 variables (connectivity between pairs of brain areas) with certain condition (1/0), in a sample of 90 individuals.

PCA has been more and more used for dimensionality reduction in these kind of studies, becoming extremely popular in the last two years in neuroscience, but I have some concerns about its use because of instability of results in samples where the ratio observations:variables is so low.

**Is there a possible way to determine if a PC analysis is inadequate/adequate to perform in a given small sample size with an extremely high number of variables?** (Like in my example)

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: There is no mathematical limitation on PCA whatsoever (you could perform it with a single observation if you like), so we need more information: what *statistical* assumptions and conclusions are you planning to make?